# Windows 10 "upgrade" trashed grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I just "upgraded" from Windows 7 to Windows 10. In the process, it broke came up in grub rescue, so I loaded Boot-Repair and did the recommended repair. Now instead of booting into grub, it just boots Windows 10. Is there some magic in Boot-Repair to get it to boot grub and show all the possible partitions to boot? Boot-Repair suggested I ask here. My partition info is at:
[partition info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/18715307)

Thanks!

Comment: _Boot-Repair_ suggested you ask here?   They are offshoring their forums and support to AskUbuntu?

Comment: @gravity the developer is/was around here too: http://askubuntu.com/users/38610/lovinbuntu Given the amount of questions generated and how they turned out, it's probably not the best or most effective way to manage a project.

Comment: Actually, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair which suggests asking here.